# Separting Theorem from the origin

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, inner-products

I have the set $C:=C(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of convex combinations of $x_i$'s. I know that there exists an $x_i$ such that $\Vert x_i \Vert > 0$ and $ 0 \notin \mathring{C}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i x_i : \lambda_i \in (0,1) \text{ and sum up to 1}\}$. I also know that there exists a unique $ y \in C$ such that $\Vert y \Vert = d(0,C)$ and the following holds: \begin{align*}\>\forall c \in \mathring{C} : \> \langle y , c \rangle > 0. \end{align*}  Now I am supposed to show that $\langle y , x_i \rangle > 0$ holds.

Can somebody give me a hint for this task?

Comment: What does $y=d(0,C)$ mean?

Comment: @Michael $d(0,C)$ is the distance from 0 to the set $C$ and = means defined as in this context.

Comment: If $y$ is a distance then it is a scalar, and taking an inner product between scalar $y$ and vector $c$ does not make sense.

Comment: @Michael You are right. It should be $ y \in C$  such that $\Vert y \Vert := d(0,C)$. Thanks, I will edit the original post.

Comment: Is that last inequality supposed to be strict? Otherwise I don't think it's true. For example, take $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 \neq 0$. Then $C$ is a line segment. Also, $\mathring{C}$ will be the interior of the line segment (which doesn't include $0$), and $y = 0$. But then $\langle y, x_i \rangle = 0$.

Comment: @TheoBendit : In that case $\langle y,c\rangle >0$ fails, since $y=0$.

Comment: @Michael: Good point. I didn't realise from the wording that this was an assumption, and not a previously formed conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall Kolmogorov's inequality: given a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $z \in C$, then $z$ is the projection of $x$ onto $C$ if and only if $\langle x - z, c - z \rangle \le 0$ for all $c \in C$. In our case, $x = 0$ and $z = y$, so
$$\langle y, c - y \rangle \ge 0 \implies \langle y, c \rangle \ge \|y\|^2 > 0,$$
since $\langle c, y \rangle > 0$, and hence $y \neq 0$. This holds for all $c \in C$, not just $\mathring{C}$, including the points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

Comment: Should it be $\langle x - z , c - z \rangle \ge 0$?. Anyway thanks for the answer!

Comment: No, what's written is right. The sign changed because $x = 0$ and $z = y$, so we get $\langle 0 - y, c - y \rangle \le 0$.